# Where do the recaps/flashbacks of Felicity Smoak come from in S01E04?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

At the beginning of every episode of *The Flash*, there are some recap shots. For episode 4, those consist of some shots of Felicity Smoak asking about Barry and being introduced to Iris. Yet I don't remember from the previous episodes that she was in them.

Can someone point out what I missed or is this extra information and not a recap from earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's from the "The Man Under the Hood", the nineteenth episode of the second season of Arrow.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid it would be from Arrow (can't find the time yet to catch up on that) but I wasn't sure if/why they would use recaps from another series, it only adds confusion to those who don't follow both.

Comment: I don't follow Arrow, really happy to see this answer. Thanks

Comment: Yea, the episode was used as a background pilot for Flash.